# why yii errorhandler didn't capture CDbexception

Tags: php, yii

In my project , there is a CDbexception message

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.xxx' doesn't exist

dsiplay on the web page when database table is not exist , 
in here i want use customer page to instead of the CDBexception page,but now i found the Yii errorHandler can't capture this error .

so what additional configuration should be configured in YII framework ?

Comment: what is your configuration for handling yii error? you try anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do several thing:

1) Surround the code that could throw the error with a try catch:

```
try {
    //your sql code
} catch(CDbException $e) {
    // you redirect the user to the appropriate page, ...
}
```

2) Use the [build-in error handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action)

You activate it in your configuration file:

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
    ),
);
```

In the configuration we used the action `site/error` so you need to have it in your project. You can create this method like:

```
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        $this->render('error', $error);
}
```

ps: the code is from the yii guide!

Comment: accroding you way , it's mean i have to use "try catch" with the every sql execution ?

Comment: Oh no! You should rely on the build-in error handler! It's just for some sql execution that you know could throw an exception that you wish to handle then you should use the try catch. For example in my project sometime I can have a CDbException because of foreign keys. I know that I can have this error and I want to continue the process if this exception is thrown so I use a try catch. this way the user doesn't even know that an error occured!

Comment: The original title says "why yii errorhandler didn't capture CDbexception" and all we're responding in here is how to create an error handler, so this does not respond the original question at all. I have the same problem: I do have an error handler and is not handling CDbExceptions, so I still need to find out why as OP requested,

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause for this error to happen is that your controller for handling `CDbexception` is also throwing a new `CDbexception` inside `onInit()`, `beforeAction()` and/or the HTML template.
To prevent this "double throw" just add a try-catch wherever this second exception is/are being thrown.